# html checked="checked" cannot get css :checked

Tags: css, forms, radio-button

When applying *checked="checked"* to a radio input the corresponding CSS does not seem to work (:checked)

What am I missing?

[image]

....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using `checked` only without the colon in front of it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Kendo controls can sometimes be a bit difficult when trying to override their provided styles.  If I correctly understood your question and example, it seems you are trying to change the background and border properties of the entire radio button control?

In the case of your given example, you'll need to target the label for the control, not the control itself.  To do this, you can use the [Adjacent Sibling Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp#:%7E:text=Try%20it%20Yourself%20%C2%BB-,Adjacent%20Sibling%20Selector,-(%2B)) to select the label for the control since in your example it is positioned immediately after the control you are targeting.  This looks like: `.k-radio:not(:checked) + label.k-radio-label` in the example I provided below.

```css
input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox],
input.k-checkbox,
input.k-radio {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked),
input[type=radio]:not(:checked),
.k-checkbox:not(:checked),
.k-radio:not(:checked)+label.k-radio-label {
  background-color: #EBF1FD;
  border-color: #B8D8F7;
  border-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


<label>Kundentyp</label>
<div class="input">
  <input type="radio" name="kndtyp" id="kndtyp0" class="k-radio ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid -ng-invalid-required" ng-disabled="info.contact.usr" ng-value="'0'" ng-model="info.contact.kndtyp" required="required" checked="checked" value="0">
  <label class="k-radio-label" for="kndtyp0">naturlich</label>
  <input type="radio" name="kndtyp" id="kndtyp1" class="k-radio ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" ng-disabled="info.contact.usr" ng-value="'1'" ng-model="info.contact.kndtyp" required="required" checked="checked" value="1">
  <label class="k-radio-label" for="kndtyp1">juristisch</label>
</div>
```